# Replacing Image in ScrollViewer while doing a zoom gesture

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I am creating a photo viewing app and I want to implement zooming for the picture. I created a ScrollViewer and placed an Image there. It all works out of the box. I can do a zoom gesture and it zooms into the picture. Now, next thing I want to implement is to load high resolution version of the picture when the zoom gesture starts and dynamically swap the bitmap in the Image control when its loaded. I want it to happen seamlessly, so that user can continue the gesture and keep zooming in and see a more detailed picture.
What is the best approach to accomplish this?
This is the code that I currently have. The problem with my code is that when the Image.Source is replaced my gesture is interrupted and photo is reset to the original size. Changing ScrollViewer ZoomFactor doesn't help as it seems to get reset when the Image is being replaced.
I have a DataModel with an Image property that initially returns null but starts loading a picture from a 'file' in a low resolution mode and calls OnPropertyChanged("Image") when load is finished. Calling LoadFullImage() loads full resolution version and calls OnPropertyChanged("Image") when finished.

Here are extracts from DataModel.cs:

```
public async Task LoadFullImage()
    {
        loadFullImageTask = UpdateImage(0);
        await loadFullImageTask;
    }

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get
        {
            if (fullImage != null)
            {
                return fullImage;
            }
            else if (image != null)
            {
                return image;
            }
            else
            {
                Task loadImageTask = UpdateImage(768);

                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool FullImageLoading
    {
        get { return (this.loadFullImageTask != null) && (!this.loadFullImageTask.IsCompleted); }
    }

    public bool FullImageLoaded
    {
        get { return this.fullImage != null; }
    }
```

Here is my MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="imageViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinZoomFactor="1" ZoomMode="Enabled" ViewChanged="imageViewer_ViewChanged">
        <Image x:Name="image" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Image}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Here is my MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        StorageFile file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        data = new DataModel(file);
        imageViewer.DataContext = data; 
    }

    private async void imageViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer imageViewer = (ScrollViewer)sender;

        if (imageViewer.ZoomFactor > 1)
        {
            if (!data.FullImageLoaded && (!data.FullImageLoading))
            {
                int oldHeight = ((BitmapImage)data.Image).PixelHeight;
                int oldWidth = ((BitmapImage)data.Image).PixelWidth;
                double oldHOffset = imageViewer.HorizontalOffset;
                double oldVOffset = imageViewer.VerticalOffset;

                await data.LoadFullImage();

                int newHeight = ((BitmapImage)data.Image).PixelHeight;
                int newWidth = ((BitmapImage)data.Image).PixelWidth;

                float ratio = (float)oldHeight / (float)newHeight;
                imageViewer.MaxZoomFactor = imageViewer.MaxZoomFactor * ratio;
                imageViewer.MinZoomFactor = imageViewer.MinZoomFactor * ratio;
                imageViewer.ZoomToFactor(imageViewer.ZoomFactor * ratio);
                //imageViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(oldHOffset / ratio);
                //imageViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(oldVOffset / ratio);
            }
        }
    }
```

As I already mentioned, the problem with this code is that the gesture gets interrupted and a new image is not resized/scrolled to the correct position, user experience is not seamless.
Thanks for any suggestions on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write this code for you because it would be too much, but here are the steps:

1. The image needs to have a ScaleTransform applied to its RenderTransform property. You will use this to cause it to 'zoom' when the user is pinching or stretching.
2. Detect the pinch gesture using the Manipulation events; you can even filter to only the pinch gesture if it helps you reduce some code. These events will be the most reliable.
3. The Manipulation events will return how much pinch or stretch is occurring, this needs to correspond to how much zoom you apply to the image's ScaleTransform in number 1.
4. In code-behind you can create a BitmapImage that points to and loads the image from the server. Once it has been loaded, you can replace the source of the image the user is pinching. This will be nearly seamless to the user unless the high-res image is multi-megabytes. Don't do that.

Please note that my steps do not include a ScrollViewer. A ScrollViewer can certainly wrap the image, but the work itself is done as part of the Image itself.

I might also point you to the `MultiScaleImage` control that you might want to steal some logic from in order to do this best: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.multiscaleimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

There's one more thing. This can be accomplished quite easily with DeepZoom. Since it is not yet available in XAML, it doesn't mean you can't leverage a WebView to accomplish this. It would give you a pre-built, insanely scalable (and free) solution. But the choice is yours.

Comment: Jerry, I thought the approach with ScaleTransform was needed when ScrollViewer didn't support zoom gesture. Currently it works perfect with a single picture - i can zoom in very smoothly. Also my ScrollViewer is contained in the FlipView control and gestures from both ScrollViewer and FlipView controls work great together: i can flip images and zoom in when needed. Are you saying that it's impossible to switch images seamlessly in ScrollViewer?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone remember this thread? =) ok,
I've implemented the 'Replacing image during zooming' on [my app](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/app/pict8/04366e7f-e3f2-4dd8-aa4b-629223935359).
As @Vitary mentioned above, if the size of 'content' is changed, the scrollviewer reset zoom ratio and X/Y offsets.
To avoid it, my app xaml use the following structure:

```
<FlipView>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ScrollViewer>
      <ViewBox> <-- This size is same with original image width/height. No change during zoom in/out.
        <Image/>  <-- This size is vary.
      </ViewBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </DataTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

By keeping the size of viewbox as same, you can avoid the reset of scroll viewer.
My implementation is...

1. User select the item of flipview. At this sequence, viewsource code set the w/h of original image to viewsource member. This member is binded to the w/h of viewbox.
2. Do low-res decoding. then set to image control by binding. As you know, viewbox can stretch the content to fit the size of viewbox automatically.
3. When user make zoom gesture, the codebehind notify ViewModel. The ViewModel start original-res decoding, then set the image to image control by binding. During this sequence, the scroll viewer can keep offset and zoom ratio. Because, the size of viewbox is not changed. The switching from low-res to original res is smooth and without glitch.